# "This site is under development" when sharing on Facebook

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, sharing

I have some issues when sharing my website's url on Facebook. There is a text saying "**This site is under development**", and there is no thumbnail. That only happens when sharing the main url (the url of my site). When I share an url from a post, or another page of my site, this does not happen. It only happen when sharing my front page url.

This is the url with that problem

http://www.randomizado.com/

As I said, this problem doesn't happen with a page url like this:
http://www.randomizado.com/contacto/

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Click the [check mark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SEk.png) to mark the answer that solved your problem as The Solution.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook caches shared links. Maybe you/someone else tried sharing the site when it was still under development and it hasn't been updated on Facebook since. Try this: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug